# не работает проверка на количество символов

Tags: php

не работает проверка на количество символов

```
  /* Принимаем данные из формы */
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $page_id = $_POST["page_id"];
  $text_comment = $_POST["text_comment"];
  if (mb_strlen($name)<5  || mb_strlen($name)>90)
  {
    header('location: /error/index.html');
    exit;
    }
    elseif (mb_strlen($text_comment)<10 ||  mb_strlen($text_comment)>1600)
      {
      header('location: /error/index.html');
      exit;
    }
  $name = htmlspecialchars($name);// Преобразуем спецсимволы в HTML-сущности
  $text_comment = htmlspecialchars($text_comment);// Преобразуем спецсимволы в HTML-сущности
  $mysql = new mysqli('remotemysql.com','3u5SxxxWnv','4VxvDT64ar','3u5SxxxWnv');// Подключается к базе данных
  $mysql->query("INSERT INTO comments (name, page_id, text_comment) VALUES ('$name', '$page_id', '$text_comment')");// Добавляем комментарий в таблицу
  header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);// Делаем реридект обратно
?>
```

Comment: Стало хуже - куда исчезли `||` в ифах?

Comment: @u_mulder а они были?) Просто уже ответ писал ;)

Comment: Были, в истории правок видны.

Comment: @u_mulder да вижу, тогда пока не понятно в чем проблема, да и мои советы использовать PDO были проигнорированы :/

Comment: Лучше бы вместо каши в виде if - elseif    для каждого блока поставили отдельную проверку, так вам легче будет понять/поймать ошибку. В каком блоке  "не работает проверка" ? проверяли вы какие данные прилетают в name  и text_comment ?

Comment: все заработало , всем спасибо

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` предназначены для перевода текста в хтмл-представление; они не защищают полностью от иньекций

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov по-моему, у вас навязчивая идея с этими инъекциями. Причем тут это замечание? Вопрос-то не в этом. Может, сайт локальный вообще и там заботиться о защите от инъекций не нужно. Ну и уж если инспектировать код, почему только про инъекции? В этом коде (и во многих других подобных ответах) много чего сделано не лучшим образом.

Comment: @Максим Степанов, да это параноя обычная ... я ж не в ответ написал ... а вопроса "об этом" не будет ... ну, можете тоже докопаться до чего-нибудь не лучшего ... я вот, в соседнем вопросе намекнул, что писать страницу кода с переменными s1,s2,s3 -- не особо.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov в целом да, согласен )